# python ошибка requests при запросе get на другой сайт, когда использую прокси

Tags: python, requests, proxy

Я уже ломаю голову который час, не могу разобраться с данной ошибкой и прошу у вас помощи.
Вот код, где появляется ошибка:

```
import requests
with requests.Session() as s:
    proxies = {
        'http': 'http://67.205.141.168:8080', 
        'https': 'http://67.205.141.168:8080'
    }
    s.get('https://example.com/', proxies=proxies)
```

Я посылаю `get` запрос на какой-то сайт, от куда хочу получить ответ, допустим, заголовки, но суть не в этом, а в том, что посылая `get` запрос через прокси, я получаю ошибку:

`raise ProxyError(e, request=request) requests.exceptions.ProxyError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='example.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / ( Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x03CC7B80>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061]`

`get` Запрос без прокси работает отлично, а с прокси - получаю ошибку. Я нахожу прокси в списках доступных бесплатных прокси, я перепробовал много вариантов, многие из них возвращали такую ошибку, а от остальных прокси я получал ответ где-то минуты через 2-3. Почему появляется такая ошибка? Мне нужно использовать прокси именно таким способом, в коде python, но не знаю как решить эту проблему. Может есть какие-то другие способы подключиться к прокси с помощью кода python? Желательно посылать запросы с библиотекой requests. Надеюсь на вашу помощь, благодарю.

Comment: если код без прокси работает, значит код в порядке. в выводе же специально для вас написано: `ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.`. к прокси подключиться не может. пробуйте другой прокси

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Код рабочий, прокси нет. У меня тоже такая ситуация была недавно. Попробовал несколько бесплатных прокси, не работает. Решил, что в коде ошибка. Но нет, потом еще попробовал штук 20 проксей и только на 2-х сработало.

Оказывается много народа автоматически парсят эти бесплатные прокси помойки, потом чекают и нормальных остается 1% и те через несколько дней умирают. Так что проблема в бесплатных прокси.